# Probability for intersecting lines

Tags: probability

20 lines in the plane intersect with each other at distinct points. Find the probability for 3 such points to form a triangle.

Well, I assume we have 20C2 = 190 such points. Then what? We calculate 190C3 to find how many triangles we can form?
The condition we are examining is for the 3 points not to be collinear.

Comment: Each line has 19 points of intersection, any three of which are collinear.  But it is possible that a set of three points could be collinear without falling on one of the twenty lines.  Asking a probability problem requires a probability distribution for outcomes.

Comment: I would assume that for the sets of points that do not lie on the same line, the probability for them to be collinear is zero. So maybe we are looking for [19C3*20]/190C3?

Comment: That's the only sense I can make of the problem.  It is mildly interesting to think about what arrangement of lines would maximize the number of collinear triples *not* sharing one the 20 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume there are no "accidental" colinearities, you can form a triangle whenever the three points are not all on the same line.  Each line has $19$ points on it, so there are $20 {19 \choose 3}=19380$ sets of three colinear points.  There are ${190 \choose 3}=1125180$ ways to choose three points so the chance you can form a triangle is $1-\frac {19380}{1125180}=\frac{970}{987}\approx 0.983$

Another way to get there is to pick the first point.  To have the three points be colinear the second point needs to be on one of the two lines going through the first point, which is a probability of $\frac {38}{189}$.  The third point needs to be on the same line as the first two, which is a probability of $\frac {18}{188}$.  This gives a chance for no triangle of $\frac {38 \cdot 18}{189 \cdot 188}=\frac {17}{987}$ like the first approach.

Comment: Why 95C3 and not 190C3?

Comment: I had confused myself